# Placing labels with leader lines at periphery of map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, labeling, maplex, leader-line

I have a set of points I want to label with leader lines. I know how to set a defined offset for the leader lines but how do I get Maplex to place the text outside of the map and adjust the leader lines as necessary?

[image: current map]

Answer (score 2):

See instructions below:

1. Make sure the boundary layer is polygon layer
2. Set the polygon layer label property, right click layer in table of contents and select Properties, then select Label tab>Placement Properties>Conflict Resolution> and change the Interior feature weight value to 1000
3. In the Label Manager (found on the Label or Maplex toolbar) change the Offset value to something larger than the default 1 until the labels are outside the boundary polygon (maybe 40)

Comment: thanks. How does one set the boundary layer in the first place?

Comment: Right click the polygon layer in the table of contents and select Properties, and continue on with step 2 noted above.